Why equal series written in a little bit different way both diverges and converges?
I am very new to Mathematica, so I am sorry if the answer is obvious. I wanted to calculate the sum of the following series:
Sum[Exp[2*I*Pi/3*n]/(n^(1/3)), {n, 1, Infinity}]


PolyLog[1/3, (-1)^(2/3)]

But running the following command, Mathematica concludes that series diverges:
Sum[Exp[2*I*Pi/3]^n/(n^(1/3)), {n, 1, Infinity}]


Sum does not converge

I use Mathematica 13 on 64-bit Linux system. It's obvious that this series converges.
The only difference in two sums is exponent, namely in one case I use Exp[...]^n, in another case I use Exp[...*n].
Where did I make a mistake?

Use Sum[PowerExpand[Exp[2*I*Pi/3]^n]/(n^(1/3)),{n,1,Infinity}] then it works. See assumptions in PowerExpand why and when this is valid

I don't know why, but you can use VerifyConvergence -> False, and you will get a result also for the second case.

Interestingly, SumConvergence[Exp[2 I π/3]^n/(n^(1/3)), n, Method -> "DivergenceTest"] gives True but SumConvergence[Exp[2 I π/3]^n/(n^(1/3)), n, Method -> "RaabeTest"] gives False ...

Fyi, in Maple, it gives same answer for both forms. i.e. it combined powers automatically. Here is  screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/IHuxhgWk.png it looks like in Mathematica the different form of input made it go to different code path.

@Nasser I find it a little bit strange

@Domen: As far as I understand it, the Raabe test works only for series of real terms, but the series under consideration is complex-valued.

@Domen: SumConvergence[ComplexExpand[Re[Exp[2 I \[Pi]/3]^n]]/(n^(1/3)), n,   Method -> "RaabeTest"] returns SumConvergence[Cos[(2 n \[Pi])/3]/n^(1/3), n, Method -> "RaabeTest"].

@user64494, my point is that if Raabe test is inconclusive, it should return unevaluated, not False. This has nothing to do with complex vs. real-valued terms.

There is a simple workaround:
Sum[ComplexExpand[Exp[2*I*Pi/3]^n]/(n^(1/3)), {n, 1, Infinity}]


PolyLog[1/3, (-1)^(2/3)]


Yes, that's a good way of solving this issue, but I am still I little bit confused why the system tells that the series diverges in first case and I find it a little bit weird. Usually you don't expect such behaviour

@NeoFanatic: Don't know it. The series under consideration converges only conditionally.  BTW, SumConvergence[Exp[2*I*Pi/3]^n/(n^(1/3)), n] produces False.

This doesn't answer the question why.

@Domen: You are right. The reason of the bugs in SumConvergence[Exp[2*I*Pi/3]^n/(n^(1/3)), n] and Sum[Exp[2*I*Pi/3]^n/(n^(1/3)), {n, 1, Infinity}] is the question to the developers.

@user64494 Please refrain from insulting others. I will edit out the insult.

@C.E. Sorry, I state the fact Sum does not converge ,  no more and no less.
